# extract data from each pdf in a folder

Tags: python, pdf

pic below is the code and output of my pdf, what would like is to extract the data in each pdf file in a folder and paste into an excel file, below is also my initial python code

[image]

update with code from Jorj but error on [words = page.get_text("words", sort=True):]

```
    import os
import fitz
import pandas as pd

# Specify the folder containing the PDF files
folder = r'C:\Users\WORK\Downloads\Invoice Verification'

# Create an empty list to store the data
data = []

# Iterate through each PDF file in the folder
with fitz.open(filename) as doc:
    filename = doc.name
    for page in doc:
        words = page.get_text("words", sort=True):
        for i, word in enumerate(words):
            if word[4] == "Date:"  # item 4 is the actual word string
                date = words[i + 1][4]  # the date as a string
            elif word[4] == "Total:"
                total = float(words[i + 1][4])
            elif word[4] == "Invoice":  # here we need to skip over "No."
                invoice_no = words[i + 2][4]

        # Add the data to the list
        data.append([filename, invoice_no, date, total])

# Convert the data to a DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["File Name", "Invoice No.", "Date", "Total"])

# Write the DataFrame to an Excel spreadsheet
df.to_excel("invoice_data.xlsx", index=False)
```

link to file - https://ufile.io/r2qbw2yz

desired output
[image]

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @JorjMcKie would like to extract the values of file name, invoice no., date and total

Comment: Please avoid pasting code images, paste your code **and** the output of it as a code block, and if you are using a pdf supply us with an option to get this pdf for testing :)

Comment: @LidorEliyahuShelef link to sample file - https://ufile.io/r2qbw2yz

Comment: Good, I would suggest adding it to the question body, plus what is the desired result you wish to get?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to extract data of interest:

**File name:** simply take `doc.name`, it will contain "Invoice 1.pdf" in the above case. If you don't like the file extension use `os.path.splitext(doc.name)[0]` instead.

For text extraction, there are half a dozen of different variants available in PyMuPDF, to address different requirements for performance vs. info detail.

In your case it seems that extracting single words (= strings without spaces in between) is the best alternative. When sorting that output in reading sequence, you should find e.g. the date as the word following the word with a text equal to "Date:". Here is a snippet:

```py
with fitz.open(filename) as doc:
    for page in doc:
        words = page.get_text("words", sort=True)
        for i, word in enumerate(words):
            if word[4] == "Date:"  # item 4 is the actual word string
                date = words[i + 1][4]  # the date as a string
            elif word[4] == "Total:"
                total = float(words[i + 1][4])
            elif word[4] == "Invoice":  # here we need to skip over "No."
                invoice_no = words[i + 2][4]
            # any other data ...
```

Comment: i get invalid syntax on `words = page.get_text("words", sort=True):`

Comment: @k1dr0ck - sorry making the correction

Comment: @k1dr0ck remove ":" at end of line.

Comment: invalid syntax now on `if word[4] == "Date:"`

Answer (score 0):

You can do it simply by drag and drop or other means in windows to tailor a batch file but for simple illustration of method concept, many python users already have poppler utilities (https://github.com/oschwartz10612/poppler-windows) or as shown here you can also use the xpdf version (http://www.xpdfreader.com/download.html)

[image]

Where I have `type output.csv` you would put your own call to excel and remove the `& pause` but keep `GOTO :eof` on the line below so any action does not fall into the subroutine

**Invoices.bat** OR invoices.cmd (does not matter what you name either one)

```
@echo off
set "popplerbin=c:\apps\pdf\xpdf\xpdf-tools-win-4.04\bin64"
set "folder=C:\Users\WORK\Downloads\Invoice Verification"

echo "File Name","Invoice No.","Date","Total" >output.csv
for /R "%folder%" %%d in ("IN*.pdf") do CALL :one_row "%%d"

type output.csv & pause
 
GOTO :eof
:one_row
"%popplerbin%\pdftotext.exe" -layout "%~dpn1.pdf" %temp%\tmp.txt
FOR /F "usebackq tokens=3 delims= " %%i IN (`find /i "invoice no." %temp%\tmp.txt`) DO set "ColB=%%i"
FOR /F "usebackq tokens=2 delims= " %%i IN (`find /i "date:" %temp%\tmp.txt`) DO set "ColC=%%i"
FOR /F "usebackq tokens=2 delims= " %%i IN (`find /i "total:" %temp%\tmp.txt`) DO set "ColD=%%i"
echo "%~n1","%ColB%","%ColC%","%ColD%" >>output.csv
exit /b
```

Comment: do i need to install xpdf? then remove 'pause &' and save as a bat file?